# Continuity of the partial derivatives of a function

Tags: limits, continuity, partial-derivative

Let
$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
          \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
          0 & (x,y) = (0,0)
       \end{cases}
$

To show that the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ aren't continuous at the point $(0,0)$, my professor showed that the $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f_x(x,y)$ and $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f_y(x,y)$ do not exist. However, from the equations of both partial derivatives we can already determine that both are not defined at $(0,0)$ (the denominator of both equations are $x^2+y^2$). My question is, by the definition of continuity, since $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ are not defined, can't we directly state that the partial derivatives are not continuous at $(0,0)$ without having to show that the limits do not exist?

Comment: What is the function $f$?

Comment: @AndrewZhang I just added the function $f$

Comment: The partials exist at the origin for $f$, and are both $0$.

Comment: $f_x = \frac{y(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$. So I thought $f_x(0,0)$ isn't defined?

Comment: You can't apply any derivative rules at 0, unfortunately. You need to calculate it directly from the definition, which fortunately, is trivial here. To calculate $f_x(0,0)$, we simply observe that $f(a,0) = 0$ for every $a$, so that $f_x(0,0) = 0$. And by symmetry, $f_y(0,0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way of thinking.
We know $f \in C^1(A)$ $\implies$ $f$ differentiable in $A$ and $f$ differentiable in $x_0$ $\implies$ $f \in C(I_{x_0})$ with $I_{x_0}$ neighbourhood of $x_0$.
Clearly $f$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$ [using polar coordinates, the limit depends on $\vartheta$].
$f$ not continuous in $(0,0)$ $\implies$ $f$ not differentiable in $I_{(0,0)}$ $\implies$ $f \notin C^1(I_{(0,0)})$